# How do I use Click Element function with robot framework when the element does not have id or name?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I'm currently using the Selenium2Library in robot framework to automate some web tests. Currently, I'm having problems automating the click of a login button with the Click Element function.

This is the element I would like to use:

`<a class="transparentBtn loginLink ng-scope" ng-click="commonService.gigyaRaasLogin()" translate="BTN_ADMIN_LOGIN_WATCHLIST">LOGIN</a>`

and this is the xpath if I copy from the console:
`//*[@id="menu"]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a`

I have trouble finding which locator to use if I want to click this element.

These are some of the things I've tried so far:

1. `Click Element  css=a.loginLink`
2. `Click Element  link=LOGIN`

Comment: What about: `xpath=//a[contains(text(), 'LOGIN')]`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I got the same error as before: 

ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//a[contains(text(), 'LOGIN')]' did not match any elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to locate unique css (1 matching node) or  try this

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath=//*[@id="menu"]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a      10
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="menu"]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently what was missing was the "Wait Until Element Is Visible" function because the website starts off with a loading animation.
I would assume that all the other solution posted would work too if I had included the "Wait Until Element Is Visible".

Answer (score 9):

I recommend to be a bit more flexible. The good approach if you find the balance between define flexible and unique. Otherwise the smallest site change will breake your test.

Following example should match on the previous example:

- Match on any link that contain LOGIN text

  ```
  Click Element       //a[contains(text(),'LOGIN')]
  ```
- Match on any element that contain LOGIN text

  ```
  Click Element       //*[contains(text(),'LOGIN')]
  ```
- Match on any element where the class attribute equal with  "transparentBtn loginLink ng-scope"

  ```
  Click Element       //a[@class="transparentBtn loginLink ng-scope"]
  ```
- You can check multiple attributes at the same time

  ```
  Click Element       //a[@class='transparentBtn loginLink ng-scope' and @ng-click='commonService.gigyaRaasLogin()']
  ```
- You can use contains() to check if string part of the class attribute

  ```
  Click Element       //a[contains(@class,'loginLink')]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, the Selenium2Library supports many different locators. The most expressive is xpath, which can be used to find just about anything. See the section Locating or specifying elements in the [Selenium2Library documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html).

In your case, if you are clicking on a link then `click link  link=LOGIN` should work. If it doesn't, it could be that the link is in an iframe, or perhaps it's hidden by css (some frameworks like angular and react will hide elements and replace them with their own thing)

Answer (score 0):

For clicking the the button in robot framework:-

```
Press keys   Locator_here   ENTER
```

It will work------