# Unable to locate elements using XPath in Robot Framework

Tags: xcode, appium, robotframework, appium-ios

I am trying to Input Text into a `XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField`. So far I have tried the following methods:

```
Input Text    //XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name="Email"]    abcd@gmail.com
```

The element is visible but got the error message as

> ValueError: Element locator
> '//XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField[@name=“Password”]' did not match any
> elements.

I am using iOS SDK version: 14.0 and Appium version: 1.19.1

My DOM:

```
<XCUIElementTypeTextField type="XCUIElementTypeTextField" value="Email" name="Email" label="" enabled="true" visible="true" x="35" y="395" width="344" height="41"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Input Text    xpath=//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name="Email"]    abcd@gmail.com
```

why don't you use the name=? (this would easily work as well)

```
Input Text  name=Email  Test
```

[How do I use Click Element function with robot framework when the element does not have id or name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324287/how-do-i-use-click-element-function-with-robot-framework-when-the-element-does-n/45353417)